# High Security Setup : Is it possible to access Db2 server through proxy from windows client?

Tags: db2, db2-luw, catalog, federation

We are planning to use ManageEngine Applications Manager Paid Utility- application performance monitor that includes Db2 monitoring on Windows platform. That Win machine is restricted from accessing Db2 Linux machine (server).
So thinking about a proxy server here.
Is it possible to catalog the remote db from that Windows client through the proxy machine?
Any detailed steps or guide is appreciated.

Merci.

Comment: Please edit your question (do not use comments), to add facts. What do you mean "Windows is restricted from accessing Db2" (do you mean that one or more firewalls prevent it, or do you mean it is a different network with no permitted routes between them).  Do you understand the concept of tunnelling with the ssh protocol?

Comment: Any proxy should do the trick. The client (Windows) machine only sees a host and a port, It doesn't know if that's the real database, another Windows machine, a Linux server, or any other network appliance. So long that host/port proxies into the the DB2 database all should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Db2 Server / Db2 Connect products can act as a proxy.

Linux (Server):
hostname: host1
port: 50000
database: DBNAME

Proxy Server:
Install Db2 Server product (it may be even free Db2 Community Edition), create Db2 instance
hostname: proxy
port: 50001 (or whatever, it's just for clarity)

Catalog the Linux database under this created instance:

```
db2 catalog tcpip node lin_node remote host1 server 50000
db2 catalog db DBNAME at node lin_node
```

Windows Client:
Catalog the database on Proxy:

```
db2 catalog tcpip node prx_node remote proxy server 50001
db2 catalog db DBNAME at node prx_node
```

Comment: Merci Mark and Mao. No sorry, what do you mean by tunnelling with ssh? Marks example doesn't have it, right?

Comment: Is federation a possible solution for this?

Comment: ssh tunneling (port forwarding) means, that instead of installing Db2 on `proxy` you may run there: `ssh -L 0.0.0.0:50001:localhost:50000 [someuser@]host1` presuming, that ssh server is running on `proxy`. This makes all incoming requests to port 50001 on `proxy` be forwarded to port 50000 on `host1`. Windows Client `db2 catalog` commands remain the same. Db2 Federation is not suitable here at all.

Comment: So cool Mark. Merci. Does IBM have documented steps anywhere for these both approaches (install DB2 on proxy  or via ssh tunnel)? Would love to see the detailed steps for both approaches and pros/cons.

Comment: The process of installing Db2 server, creating and configuring an instance, remote database registration on proxy is not different from any other regular Db2 server installation and configuration. There is only a short statement in the doc on this: [Application proxy firewalls](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=support-application-proxy-firewalls). Refer to the `Db2 Connect` functionality description in the doc for more details. There are no any official comparisons of pros and cons with the SSH port forwarding approach. Use the most suitable one for your environment.